# Can I speed up type conversion using intrinsics?

Tags: c++11, simd, intrinsics

I am working on an application which needs to convert data to float.
The data are unsigned char or unsigned short.

I am using both AVX2 and other SIMDs intrinsics in this code.
I wrote the conversion like this:

#### unsigned char -> float :

```
#ifdef __AVX2__

__m256i tmp_v =_mm256_lddqu_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(src+j));

v16_avx[0] = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi16(_mm256_extractf128_si256(tmp_v,0x0));
v16_avx[1] = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi16(_mm256_extractf128_si256(tmp_v,0x1));

v32_avx[0] = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(_mm256_extractf128_si256(v16_avx[0],0x0));
v32_avx[1] = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(_mm256_extractf128_si256(v16_avx[0],0x1));
v32_avx[2] = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(_mm256_extractf128_si256(v16_avx[1],0x0));
v32_avx[3] = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(_mm256_extractf128_si256(v16_avx[1],0x1));

for (int l=0; l<4; l++) {
    __m256 vc1_ps = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(_mm256_and_si256(v32_avx[l],m_lt_avx[l]));
    __m256 vc2_ps = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(_mm256_and_si256(v32_avx[l],m_ge_avx[l]));

    /*
      ....
      some processing there.
      */
}

#endif

#ifdef __SSE2__

#ifdef __SSE3__
__m128i tmp_v = _mm_lddqu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(src+j));
#else
__m128i tmp_v = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(src+j));
#endif

#ifdef __SSE4_1__
v16[0] = _mm_cvtepu8_epi16(tmp_v);
tmp_v = _mm_shuffle_epi8(tmp_v,mask8);
v16[1] = _mm_cvtepu8_epi16(tmp_v);

v32[0] = _mm_cvtepi16_epi32(v16[0]);
v16[0] = _mm_shuffle_epi32(v16[0],0x4E);
v32[1] = _mm_cvtepi16_epi32(v16[0]);

v32[2] = _mm_cvtepi16_epi32(v16[1]);
v16[1] = _mm_shuffle_epi32(v16[1],0x4E);
v32[3] = _mm_cvtepi16_epi32(v16[1]);

#else

__m128i tmp_v_l = _mm_slli_si128(tmp_v,8);
__m128i tmp_v_r = _mm_srli_si128(tmp_v,8);

v16[0] = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(tmp_v,tmp_v_l);
v16[1] = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(tmp_v,tmp_v_r);

tmp_v_l = _mm_srli_epi16(v16[0],8);
tmp_v_r = _mm_srai_epi16(v16[0],8);

v32[0] = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(v16[0],tmp_v_l);
v32[1] = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(v16[0],tmp_v_r);

v16[0] = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(tmp_v,tmp_v_l);
v16[1] = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(tmp_v,tmp_v_r);

tmp_v_l = _mm_srli_epi16(v16[1],8);
tmp_v_r = _mm_srai_epi16(v16[1],8);

v32[2] = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(v16[1],tmp_v_l);
v32[3] = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(v16[1],tmp_v_r);

#endif

for (int l=0; l<4; l++) {
    __m128 vc1_ps = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_and_si128(v32[l],m_lt[l]));
    __m128 vc2_ps = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_and_si128(v32[l],m_ge[l]));
    /*
      ...
      some processing there.
    */
}
#endif
```

### unsigned short -> float

```
#ifdef __AVX2__
v32_avx[0] = _mm256_cvtepu16_epi32(_mm256_extractf128_si256(tmp_v,0x0));
v32_avx[1] = _mm256_cvtepu16_epi32(_mm256_extractf128_si256(tmp_v,0x1));

for(int l=0;l<2;l++) {
    __m256 vc1_ps = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(_mm256_and_si256(v32_avx[l],m_lt_avx[l]));
    __m256 vc2_ps = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(_mm256_and_si256(v32_avx[l],m_ge_avx[l]));

    /*
          ...
          some processing there.
    */
}
#endif

#ifdef __SSE2__

#ifdef __SSE3__
__m128i tmp_v = _mm_lddqu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(src+j));
#else
__m128i tmp_v = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(src+j));
#endif

#ifdef __SSE4_1__
v32[0] = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(tmp_v);
tmp_v = _mm_shuffle_epi32(tmp_v,0x4E);
v32[1] = _mm_cvtepu16_epi32(tmp_v);
#else
__m128i tmp_v_l = _mm_slli_si128(tmp_v,8);
__m128i tmp_v_r = _mm_srli_si128(tmp_v,8);

v32[0] = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(tmp_v,tmp_v_l);
v32[1] = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(tmp_v,tmp_v_r);
#endif

for(int l=0;l<2;l++) {
    __m128 vc1_ps = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_and_si128(v32[l],m_lt[l]));
    __m128 vc2_ps = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_and_si128(v32[l],m_ge[l]));
    /*
      ...
      some processing there.
    */

 }

#endif
```

The processing in the comments have nothing to do with the conversion step.

I would like to speed up those conversions.

I read in [SSE: convert short integer to float](/q/9161807/4850040) and in [Converting Int to Float/Float to Int using Bitwise](/q/20302904/4850040) that it's possible to do this using bitwise operations.
Are those approaches really any faster?

I experimented with the implementation in the first link; there was almost no change in processing time, it worked fine for signed short and also for unsigned short as long as the value is included between 0 and MAX_SHRT (32767 on my system):

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void convert_sse_intrinsic(const ushort *source,const int len, int *destination)
{
    __m128i zero2 =  _mm_setzero_si128();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i+=4)
    {
    __m128i value = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(_mm_set_epi64x(0,*((long long*)(source+i)) /**ps*/), zero2);
    value = _mm_srai_epi32(_mm_slli_epi32(value, 16), 16);
    _mm_storeu_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(destination+i),value);
    }
}

void convert_sse_intrinsic2(const ushort *source,const int len, int *destination)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i+=8)
    {

        __m128i value = _mm_loadu_si128(reinterpret_cast<const __m128i*>(source+i));

        _mm_storeu_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(destination+i),_mm_cvtepu16_epi32(value));

        value = _mm_shuffle_epi32(value,0x4E);

        _mm_storeu_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(destination+i+4),_mm_cvtepu16_epi32(value));
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    ushort CV_DECL_ALIGNED(32) toto[16] =
                        {0,500,1000,5000,
                       10000,15000,20000,25000,
                       30000,35000,40000,45000,
                       50000,55000,60000,65000};

    int CV_DECL_ALIGNED(32) tutu[16] = {0};

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    convert_sse_intrinsic(toto,16,tutu);
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout<<"processing time 1st method : "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop-start).count()<<" : ns"<<std::endl;

    std::copy(tutu,tutu+16,std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
    std::cout<<std::endl;


    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    convert_sse_intrinsic2(toto,16,tutu);
    stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout<<"processing time 2nd method : "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop-start).count()<<" : ns"<<std::endl;

    std::copy(tutu,tutu+16,std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
    std::cout<<std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why don't you try and measure?

Comment: Which code ?
I did that why I ask that question.
The full code where I use the convertion from unsigned short to float work in approximatly in 15 micro seconds.
The function convert_sse_intrinsics work in average (over 10 iterations) in 61 nanoseconds, The function convert_sse_intrinsics2 in 58 ns.
I would to know if there is a way to speed up the convertion, and if there is how to do it.

Comment: How did you compile the code ? What command line switches did you use ? Also, how did you benchmark it ? And what was the size of data set that you used for benchmarking ?

Comment: I am under Linux I compile the code with -O1 -O2 -O3 -Og options. 
I do my benchmarks using the steady_clock time_points of the header chrono (C++11).
Then I do duration_cast in nanoseconds.
The size of the dataset I use for benchmark the first algorithm is an image of size 64 x 64 for each type. I am using an i7 Haswell familly, thanks to the intel intrisics guide website I know the number of cycle of every steps... and so on the theoretic time of processing of each.
What I am looking for is more a sort of "ugly" but portable way to accelerate the convertion from each type to float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think there is not really any faster way to convert an unsigned char or an unsigned short to float rather than the intrinsics already there.

I tried several other ways using bitwise operators, but none was significantly faster.

So I think that it's not interesting to let this topic linger any longer.